# How to create bug work item in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

We have integrated SonarQube with ADO and fetched all the Sonar Issues in a spreadsheet by using Sonar API. Now we want those sonar issues has to be created as Bug Work Item/s in ADO. is there any possibility to achieve this ?

Can we have any ADO API to create all those sonar issues as a bugs in ADO or any other process please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Azure DevOps API "[**Work Items - Create**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)" to create a new Bug work item or any other supported types of work item in the process used by your project.

1. Request HTTP URI. Replace '**`{organization}`**' and '**`{project}`**' with your actual values.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Bug?api-version=6.0
```

2. Request body. Replace '**`{issueId}`**' with your actual value.

```json
[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "value": "Bug item associated with Sonar Issue {issueId}"
    }
]
```

By this way, the API will create a new Bug item and set its title as "**Bug item associated with Sonar Issue {issueId}**".

If you want to call this API in your program code, you can reference the related [**Client Libraries**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#client-libraries).

Hope this can help you.